# What is causing the "syntax error near unexpected token `do'" and how can I fix it?

Tags: bash, osx, select

I keep getting this error:

```
./install.sh 
./install.sh: line 28: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
./install.sh: line 28: `                do'
```

When running this code (a work in progress):

```
# Set the prompt string:
PS3='Choose folder: ';

function choose() {

    # This works:
    #select folder;
    #do test -n "$folder" && echo You chose: $REPLY\) $folder && break;
    #echo 'Wrong entry, try again.';
    #continue;
    #done;

    select folder;
    do
        case $folder in
            'q')
                echo 'Exiting …';
                break;
                ;;
            *)
                do
                    test -n '$folder' && echo You chose: $REPLY\) $folder && break;
                    echo 'Wrong entry, try again.';
                    continue;
                done;
                ;;
        esac;
    done;

}

# Switch to glob folder location:
cd ~/Desktop;

# Create menu:
choose foo*;

# Do stuff with result of choose() here ...

# Exit program:
exit 0;
```

As you can probably see from above, I'm trying to create a menu that lets me choose from a list of globbed folders; unfortunately, I can't figure out why my nested `do` is creating the error I posted above.

Optimally, the user could choose from a list of directories; if they type `q`, then the program quits; if they make an invalid selection, the program makes them choose again until they pick a valid selection (or enter `q` to quit/exit).

I have yet to get the quitting part figured out completely, but before I can do that, I need to get past this `do` statement error.

**Question: What is causing the `` syntax error near unexpected token `do' `` and how can I fix it?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Missing Loop Conditional

Your syntax is invalid. You may have other problems with your code as well, but this message is likely coming from the fact that you can't have a `do` keyword as if it were a block; you need to have one of the loop conditionals as well.

You currently have:

```
        *)
            do
                test -n '$folder' && echo You chose: $REPLY\) $folder && break;
                echo 'Wrong entry, try again.';
                continue;
            done;
            ;;
```

You are missing a `for`, `while`, or `until` keyword to start your loop.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense now! Thank you for you help!!! You have put me on the right track. :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, when I get that type of error (unmatched if/else, do, while, etc) and I can't find the offending code, I make a backup of the script and start deleting chunks of code between any blocks until I just have a skeleton of control structures and that usually helps me find the missing keyword.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the tip Mark! I'm pretty new to this level of bash scripting ... It's a little different than most languages I've used to date. Tips like this are very helpful as I really want to improve my bash scripting knowledge. Much appreciated. :)